# How to catch variables leaked from a shell function (zsh)

Tags: linux, shell, script, zsh

From a testing point of view, how can I catch variables that I've defined in a shell function that I've forgotten to make local? For example:

```
foo() {
  local var1="bar"
  var2="baz"
}
```

Can I run shell code that would run `foo` and see what variables have been left set by `foo` (that is, `var2` in the example above)?

Note: I don't want to catch any variables that may have been changed by `foo`, I only want to see **newly** defined variables.